# StreamWriter and IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
IsolatedStorageFile iF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                    if (!iF.DirectoryExists("aaa"))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No directory, create!");
                        iF.CreateDirectory("aaa");
                    }
                    StreamWriter fW = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("girls\\list.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, iF));
                    fW.WriteLine(this.tb_name.Text);
```

So, I create file, or open it, and add to it content of textbox. I need append this file, but it rewrites. Please, help me to solve this problem :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `FileMode.Append`, not `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`

See this page for details [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> Append: Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FileMode.Append` for if it exists, `FileMode.Create` if it does not.

Comment: Append is sufficient. It creates the file if it does not exist.